# Computing proportions by group based on number of unique entries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have some identified users (id) using a service at certain points in time. 
I'm trying to calculate the proportion of users of certain service type per day. In this sample data, I only have one day, but I want to allow the code to work the same way if it had more days.

```
day1 = 
datetime_idx            type  id
2016-03-01 05:04:00      C    1
2016-03-01 05:24:00      A    2
2016-03-01 05:29:00      C    3
2016-03-01 05:29:00      B    4
2016-03-01 05:35:00      D    1

day1_usage = day1.groupby('type').resample('D')['id'].nunique().reset_index()
```

This gives me the following:

```
     type datetime_idx   id
0    A     2016-03-01        1
1    B     2016-03-01        1
2    C     2016-03-01        2
3    D     2016-03-01        1
```

I tried getting the proportion this way:

```
day1_usage['ratio'] = (day1_usage.groupby(['type','datetime_idx'])['id'].transform(sum) / day1_usage.groupby('datetime_idx')['id'].transform(sum))
```

This is the output I get:

```
   type    datetime_idx     id  ratio 
0    A     2016-03-01        1    0.2 
1    B     2016-03-01        1    0.2 
2    C     2016-03-01        2    0.4 
3    D     2016-03-01        1    0.2
```

But the output I want to obtain is this:

```
   type    datetime_idx     id  ratio 
0    A     2016-03-01        1    0.25 
1    B     2016-03-01        1    0.25 
2    C     2016-03-01        2    0.5 
3    D     2016-03-01        1    0.25
```

My code is dividing by the sum of user entries, but I want it to be divided by the number of unique users.

Comment: the problem is actually still unsolved

Comment: Okay. how do you calculate ratio?

Comment: ratio for type x in day1 = (number of unique users for type x in day1) / (number of unique users in day1)

Comment: For instance, this gives me the number of unique users by day: `day1.resample('D')['id'].nunique().reset_index()`. I just don't know how to make the division work.

Comment: @ScottBoston can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## EDIT

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO
```

Let's try with multiple days

```
csv_file = StringIO("""datetime_idx            type  id
2016-03-01 05:04:00      C    1
2016-03-01 05:24:00      A    2
2016-03-01 05:29:00      C    3
2016-03-01 05:29:00      B    4
2016-03-01 05:35:00      D    1
2016-03-03 05:04:00      C    1
2016-03-03 05:24:00      A    2
2016-03-03 05:29:00      C    3
2016-03-03 05:29:00      B    4
2016-03-03 05:35:00      D    1""")        

days = pd.read_csv(csv_file,sep='\s\s+')

days['datetime_idx'] = pd.to_datetime(days.datetime_idx)

days = days.set_index('datetime_idx')

print(days)

                    type  id
datetime_idx                
2016-03-01 05:04:00    C   1
2016-03-01 05:24:00    A   2
2016-03-01 05:29:00    C   3
2016-03-01 05:29:00    B   4
2016-03-01 05:35:00    D   1
2016-03-03 05:04:00    C   1
2016-03-03 05:24:00    A   2
2016-03-03 05:29:00    C   3
2016-03-03 05:29:00    B   4
2016-03-03 05:35:00    D   1

days_usage = days.groupby('type').resample('D')['id'].nunique().to_frame()

days_usage

                   id
type datetime_idx    
A    2016-03-01     1
     2016-03-02     0
     2016-03-03     1
B    2016-03-01     1
     2016-03-02     0
     2016-03-03     1
C    2016-03-01     2
     2016-03-02     0
     2016-03-03     2
D    2016-03-01     1
     2016-03-02     0
     2016-03-03     1

days_usage['ratio'] = (days_usage.unstack(0)
    .div(days.resample('D')['id'].nunique(), axis='index')).fillna(0).stack().swaplevel(0,1)

print(days_usage)
```

Output:

```
                      id  ratio
type datetime_idx           
A    2016-03-01     1   0.25
     2016-03-02     0   0.00
     2016-03-03     1   0.25
B    2016-03-01     1   0.25
     2016-03-02     0   0.00
     2016-03-03     1   0.25
C    2016-03-01     2   0.50
     2016-03-02     0   0.00
     2016-03-03     2   0.50
D    2016-03-01     1   0.25
     2016-03-02     0   0.00
     2016-03-03     1   0.25
```

Comment: size does not seem to be the correct function to compute the unique number of ids. Now after trying to apply the answers to a bigger data set, I noticed that 'size' is actually counting the number of types (since we grouped by type) instead of the number of unique users on the day. This unique number of ids by day needs to be taken from the original dataframe 'day1'

Comment: @Helk I had a few hours to reset and think about this problem again.  Let's see if this logic holds to what you are wanting.

Comment: @Helk This was a cool problem.  I had to reshape a bit to get the results you desired.  Let me know if you don't follow the logic.

Comment: I think I understood the process and I learned a couple of new commands with your answer: swaplevel and to_frame. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
day1_usage['ratio'] = (day1_usage.groupby(['type','datetime_idx'])['id'].transform(sum) / 
                       day1_usage.groupby('datetime_idx')['id'].transform('size'))
print (day1_usage)
  type datetime_idx  id  ratio
0    A   2016-03-01   1   0.25
1    B   2016-03-01   1   0.25
2    C   2016-03-01   2   0.50
3    D   2016-03-01   1   0.25
```

Comment: although it seems to work here. I'm a bit confused. The denominator seems to be counting the unique ids after they had already been counted, because the dataframe is day1_usage. How can I make this count from the dataframe day1 instead?

Comment: it seems that it worked only because of the coincidence that the number of entries in day1_usage is 4, right? not that the number of unique users in that day is 4.

Comment: @Helk - is possible add more data with desired output?

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already calculated the `day1_usage` DataFrame, the calculation could also be as simple as:

```
day1_usage['ratio'] = day1_usage.id / day1.id.nunique()
```

Result:

```
 type datetime_idx  id  ratio
0    A   2016-03-01   1   0.25
1    B   2016-03-01   1   0.25
2    C   2016-03-01   2   0.50
3    D   2016-03-01   1   0.25
```

Comment: its simplicity is nice, but it seems to be counting the unique ids in all days, instead of by day. The sample data only has one date, so that's why it seems to work.